# Find sum of 5 highest numbers in an array of 100 numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are 100 numbers present in an array and I need to find out the average of top 5 highest numbers among them.

Also in the same way the average of top 5 lowest numbers among them. How could I go about doing it?

Comment: No, I am trying to develop an algorithm for a particular graph and was stuck up on this code.

Comment: out of 3 what language are you using

Comment: Why don't you just pass through the list five times and copy the top item that hasn't been copied on a previous iteration (remembered by index), into a new list. Then you have the top 5 items and can easily find the average and sum.

Comment: So is it the sum, or the average? Your subject says one, and the body says another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Hoare's select algorithm (or the median of medians, if you need to be absolutely certain of the computational complexity), then add the top partition (and divide by its size to get the average).

This is somewhat faster than the obvious method of sorting instead of partitioning -- partitioning is (`O(N)`) where sorting is `O(N log(N) )`.

Edit: In C++, for real code (i.e., anything except homework where part of the requirement is to do the task entirely on your own) you can use `std::nth_element` to partition the input into the top 5 and everything else.

Edit2: Here's another quick demo to complement @Nils', but this one in full C++11 regalia (so to speak):

```
#include <numeric>  
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> x {1, 101, 2, 102, 3, 103, 4, 104, 5, 105, 6};

    auto pos = x.end() - 5;

    std::nth_element(x.begin(), pos, x.end());

    auto sum = std::accumulate(pos, x.end(), 0);
    auto mean = sum / std::distance(pos, x.end());

    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << '\n' << "mean = " << mean << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jerry already explained how it works. I just want to add a practical code-example in c++:

```
#include <algorithm>

int averageTop5 (int list[100])
{
  // move top 5 elements to end of list:
  std::nth_element (list, list+95, list+100);

  // get average (with overflow handling)
  int avg = 0;
  int rem = 0;      
  for (int i=95; i<100; i++)
  {
    avg += list[i]/5;
    rem += list[i]%5;      
  }

  return avg + (rem /5);  
}
```

With Jerrys std::accumulate this becomes a two-liner but may fail with integer overflows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
int averageTop5 (int list[100])
{
  std::nth_element (list, list+95, list+100);
  return std::accumulate (list+95, list+100, 0)/5;
}
```

Comment: Especially since you already have the iterators to the proper positions, I'd use `std::accumulate` to add the numbers.

Comment: did it.. wasn't aware of std::accumulate.. Nice template.

Comment: dude, use long long's and then don't worry about the overflows

Answer (score 0):

Sort them in ascending and add the last five numbers

Answer (score 0):

Copy the first 5 numbers into an array.  Determine the position of the smallest element in that array.  For each of the 95 numbers in the remainder of the list, compare it with that smallest number.  If the new number is larger, then replace it and redetermine the position of the new smallest number in your short list.

At the end, sum your array and divide by 5.